# Facebook FQL queries return {}

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using FQL to get data from user's stream to build a web page looks like wall-to-wall. With two queries:

> query = "SELECT post_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid="+user['uid']+" AND type='newsfeed') AND target_id = "+uid+" AND actor_id = "+user['uid']+" LIMIT 5"

and

> query = "SELECT post_id, message, created_time FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid="+user['uid']+" AND type='newsfeed') AND target_id = "+user['uid']+" AND actor_id = "+uid+" LIMIT 5"

they only return:

> {}

What's wrong in my queries ? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

try checking the values you are using for uid..

target_id means the wall it was posted to, ONLY if the wall was not the actor_id's wall..

Both will never be equal.